# Externalize plugin versions in kotlin gradle dsl?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I would like to externalize plugin versions.

I've tried

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

object DependencyVersions {
    const val SPRING_BOOT_VERSION = "2.1.6.RELEASE"
    const val DEPENDENCY_MANAGEMENT_VERSION = "1.0.8.RELEASE"
}

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version DependencyVersions.SPRING_BOOT_VERSION
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version DependencyVersions.DEPENDENCY_MANAGEMENT_VERSION
}
```

but I get `Unresolved reference: DependencyVersions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was until very recently still true with the Gradle API but was recently fixed. See [this issue covering version variables in the Plugin section](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1697). There is an [open issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9830) for fixing this for the Kotlin DSL.

The only way to get around this is setting the version with a PluginResolutionStrategy as suggested in the same issue in your `settings.gradle`:

```
pluginManagement {
resolutionStrategy {
    eachPlugin {
        if (requested.version == null) {
            def pluginName = requested.id.name.split('-').collect { it.capitalize() }.join().uncapitalize()
            def versionPropertyName = (requested.id.id == 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm') ?
                    "kotlinPluginVersion" : "${pluginName}PluginVersion"
            logger.info("Checking for plugin version property '$versionPropertyName'.")
            if (gradle.rootProject.hasProperty(versionPropertyName)) {
                def version = gradle.rootProject.properties[versionPropertyName]
                logger.info("Setting '${requested.id.id}' plugin version to $version.")
                useVersion version
            } else {
                logger.warn("No version specified for plugin '${requested.id.id}' and property " +
                        "'$versionPropertyName' does not exist.")
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

And adding a property with the name of the plugin suffixed by "Version" to gradle.properties, e.g. "jacksonVersion".